# Syntax Error: Import statement with multiple semi-colon

Tags: java

This might be a weird question, but a valid one. I know below statement does not have compilation error:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();;; //(with three `;` semi-colon)
```

Okay now I have written below import statement:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;;; (with three `;` semi-colon)
```

But I got below compilation error:

```
Syntax error on token ";", invalid StaticImportOnDemandDeclarationName
```

**Why?**

Comment: It is valid to add more than one semicolon on import statement. It may be another problem in your program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have here:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();;; //(with three `;` semicolons)
```

is not a statement terminated with three semicolons.  It's a statement terminated by one semi-colon, followed by two *empty statements*.

An empty statement is legal in Java, but the import section of a Java source file does not comprise statements, it's composed of import declarations.

[JLS 14.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6) defines the Empty Statement:

> An empty statement does nothing.
>
> ```
>   EmptyStatement:
>      ;
> ```
>
> Execution of an empty statement always completes normally.

A perhaps-legitimate use of the empty statement:

```
//loop forever
while (true) {;} // the body of this loop is an empty statement.
```

In other words, in your first example, you have an assignment followed by two empty statements.  The semicolons are not strictly superfluous.

The `import` section has its own grammar, and none of the grammar rules allow for an arbitrary semi-colon.  The grammar is specified by [JLS 7.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.5):

```
ImportDeclaration:
    SingleTypeImportDeclaration
    TypeImportOnDemandDeclaration   
    SingleStaticImportDeclaration   
    StaticImportOnDemandDeclaration

SingleTypeImportDeclaration:
    import TypeName ;

...
```

Comment: I tried multiple semicolons after the import statement through command line with both java 8 and java 10. Both compiled and ran but, Eclipse gives compilation error. Grammar is same as specified in the answer. Any clue why ?

Comment: @helix: Are you putting it after your *last* import statement?  The grammer for a class file is `[PackageDeclaration] {ImportDeclaration} {TypeDeclaration}` and `;` is actually a valid `TypeDeclaration`.   This is explained in a comment in JLS10 7.6: *Extra ";" tokens appearing at the level of type declarations in a compilation unit have no effect on the meaning of the compilation unit. Stray semicolons are permitted in the Java programming language solely as a concession to C++ programmers who are used to placing ";" after a class declaration.*

Comment: @mark : actually no. Anywhere. Apparently it's an open bug since 2013. Refer https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8027682?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aworklog-tabpanel

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();;; //(with three `;` semi-colon)

after first semi colon, next two semicolon represents empty statements, these are legal in java only in the class section  area,not in import section area.

thats why this generates compile time error

import java.util.ArrayList;;; (with three `;` semi-colon)